# Reading values from XML document into an Int Array c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I can't find a proper solution anywhere that I can properly understand. So if you can explain what to do, that would be great.
I'm writing a program that can read data from save file in a video game.

How can I write something in C# that will save the integers under professions into an array? I'm using XDocument right now with a variable that points to the "player" element as a root.

> var player = doc.Root.Element("player");

My initial thought was to create a variable with the profession as the root and use a forloop to save all the values of the elements within professions to an array, but I have no idea how to start that

For context this is what the XML looks like (I added some periods to show that there are other elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SaveGame xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <player>
        .
        .
        .
        <professions>
            <int>1</int>
            <int>18</int>
            <int>25</int>
            <int>13</int>
            <int>4</int>
            <int>6</int>
        </professions>
        .
        .
        .
    </player>
</SaveGame>
```

Comment: `player.Element("professions").Elements("int").Select(x =>(int)x).ToArray()`

Comment: well that was fast, thanks

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: I won't know yet, but I tested it with an online compiler and it all worked great!

Answer (score 1):

using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List <Player> players = new List<Player>() {
                new Player() { professions = new List<Profession>() {
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{100, 200, 300, 400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{1100, 1200, 1300, 1400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{2100, 2200, 2300, 2400}}
                }},
                new Player() { professions = new List<Profession>() {
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{3100, 3200, 3300, 3400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{3100, 3200, 3300, 3400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{4100, 4200, 4300, 4400}}
                }}
            };



            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<SaveGame xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                "</SaveGame>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement saveGame = doc.Root;

            foreach (Player player in players)
            {
                XElement newPlayer = new XElement("player");
                saveGame.Add(newPlayer);
                foreach (Profession profession in player.professions)
                {
                    newPlayer.Add(new XElement("professions", profession.data.Select(x => new XElement("int", x))));
                }
            }
            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    public class Player
    {
        public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profession
    {
        public int[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

You can also use xml serializer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = new SaveGame();
            saveGame.players = new List<Player>() {
                new Player() { professions = new List<Profession>() {
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{100, 200, 300, 400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{1100, 1200, 1300, 1400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{2100, 2200, 2300, 2400}}
                }},
                new Player() { professions = new List<Profession>() {
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{3100, 3200, 3300, 3400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{3100, 3200, 3300, 3400}},
                    new Profession() { data = new int[]{4100, 4200, 4300, 4400}}
                }}
            };

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));

            serializer.Serialize(writer, saveGame, ns);

        }
    }
    public class SaveGame
    {
        [XmlElement("player")]
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }

    }
    public class Player
    {
        [XmlElement("profession")]
        public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profession
    {
        [XmlElement("int")]
        public int[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Code below deserializes the xml file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGame));
            SaveGame sameGame = (SaveGame)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class SaveGame
    {
        [XmlElement("player")]
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }

    }
    public class Player
    {
        [XmlElement("profession")]
        public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profession
    {
        [XmlElement("int")]
        public int[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP already has the XML and wants to extract an array of `int`.

Comment: The OP said "How can I write something in C# that will save the integers under professions into an array?"  I will add deserialize.

Comment: Yes, "save the integers under professions into an array". I think that means the OP wants to read the XML and put the integers into an array.